# MySQL-Querys aren't working? (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, null

So, in my MySQL-Database in "Posts" I have "ID" and "Likes".
In the line where the value of ID is 3, the value of Likes is 6.

When I do:

```
$postId = 3;
$connection = mysql_connect(...);
$query = "SELECT * FROM Posts Where ID=".$postID;
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$likes = $row['Likes'];
echo $likes;
```

But this just returns nothing. When I try to print_r the $row, it also return nothing,
but the connections etc. is right. What's my mistake I made?

Comment: You're connecting with `mysql_connect` and trying to fetch an array with `mysqli_fetch_array`. That is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments, use [mysqli_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) and [mysqli_execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-execute.php) instead of `mysql_connect` if you want to fetch with `mysqli_fetch_array`.
Also, probably your result should be lowercase, i.e.  `$row['likes'];`

```
$postId = 3;
$connection = mysqli_connect(...);

$query  = "SELECT * FROM Posts Where ID=".$postID;
$result = mysqli_execute($query);
$row    = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$likes  = $row['likes'];
echo $likes;
```